# comments not available for Support Ticketing System

Tags: 7

i have a strange problem, i installed  Support Ticketing System module, enabled Support module and Support Overview, created support client, give AUTHENTICATED USER Can select client and Access Support tickets permissions. Then when a test user issued a new support ticket i couldn't comment it although comments are enabled from content type! and the user are the same, actually there are now place for the comment block!

what i expect is when an user opens a support ticket the reply for this ticket will be via comments, so it suppose to have comment available for the ticket.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: does the authenticated user have the permissions 'View Comments' and 'Post Comments' ?

Comment: yes authenticated user have those permissions

Comment: i already found that the problem within the theme itself